# Nodejs server stop accept connections after a few hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server, client

I made an application to the control of simultaneous logins, in starts everything works perfectly, however after a few hours i can not longer connect to the server, my client returns me the following error: **net :: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT** and on the server side does not happen any error like it was running correctly... code below:

CLIENT SIDE:

```js
var socket;
function connect(id) {
    socket = io.connect('http://IP:4200');
    
    
    socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        socket.emit('join', id);
    });
    
    socket.on('messages', function (data) {
        console.log('MSG: ' + data.toString());

        switch (data.toString()) {
            case "kick":
                socket.close();
                console.log("KICK!");
                break;
            case "duplicate_entry":
                socket.close();
                console.log("Another user connection!");
                break;

        }
    });
}
```

SERVER SIDE:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var clients = [];

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

function logtimestamp() {
    var log_date = new Date();
    log_date = '[' + log_date.getFullYear() + '/' + (log_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + log_date.getDate() + ' ' + log_date.getHours() + ':' + log_date.getMinutes() + ':' + log_date.getSeconds() + ']';
    return log_date;
}// FUNCTION logtimestamp


console.log("Start time: " + logtimestamp());
console.log("Server port 4200")
console.log("websocket server created!");

try {
    io.on('connection', function (client) {
        try {
            var id;
            var conexao;

            client.on('join', function (data) {
                try {
                    console.log('Client connected...'+logtimestamp()+' ID:' + data);
                    id = data;
                    conexao = {
                        ws: client,
                        id_user: data
                    };
                    clients.push(conexao);

                    for (var x = 0; x < clients.length; x++) {

                        //desconect previous user
                        try {
                            if (clients[x].id_user == id) {
                                if (clients[x].ws != conexao.ws) {
                                    clients[x].ws.emit('messages', 'duplicate_entry');
                                    clients.splice(x, 1);
                                }
                            }
                          
                        } catch (err) {
                            console.log("ERROR 1: " + err.message);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR 2: " + err.message);
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("ERROR 3: " + err.message);
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log("ERROR 4: " + err.message);
}
server.listen(4200);
```

Comment: Have you tried verbose logging to see if there are errors being logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple possible issues.  It is hard for us to know by just inspecting code which issues actually are the cause of your issue.  In any case, you should clean up these issues and see if it improves the situation:

1. You should respond the the `disconnect` event and immediately remove any socket from your `clients` array when it disconnects.
2. In your loop where you are looking to removing any prior instances of a given user, your `for` loop will not work properly when you are doing `.splice(x, 1)` in the middle of the `for` loop.  This will move all items after it does one in the array causing you to skip the comparison of the next element in the array.  One simple way to get around this is to iterate the array backwards: `for (var x = clients.length - 1; x >= 0; x--)` because then the elements who's position are affected after the `.splice()` are elements you have already looked at.  None will be missed.

Beyond this, you should examine the memory usage of the nodejs process, the open sockets by the nodejs process and the CPU usage of the nodejs process to see if any of those point to any possible issues.

And, what is your deployment environment?  Is there a proxy server in front of your web server?

Comment: yes, this "for" was a problem, however the server still stopped accepting connections, then i have changed the host and the problem has resolved, old host was hostgator and now i use digital ocean